# Facebook like button is not appearing on my webpage

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk

I can understand that this question has be asked thrice in SO, but those are outdated.

I am asking this again for current Facebook like button code. I have even tried  creating a dummy page.

Please find my code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
          <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
          <title>demo</title>
          <meta name="description" content="This page displays content " />
          <meta name="keywords" content="Free charts " />

    </head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.3";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
<p>test1.....</p>
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://mywebsite.com" data-width="400" data-layout="button_count" data-action="recommend" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>
<p>test2.....</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found something weird on this, like button is showing up only if we browse from an US IP address. If we browse from IP address of other countries, its not showing up. Appreciate your help on this !!!